# Regex to match path and filenames, extensions optional, no newlines, ignoring comments

Tags: javascript, regex

There are *many* examples for matching a filename with or without extension and path. However, I found no that my variation of that task seems to be more complicated. It is about module names in node.js `require()` statements, where the extension is optional, so it may be there or not.

I actually got pretty far, if this one bit is too complicated I can easily live with what I've got. However, curiosity drives me to ask the community. After spending most of the day on those attempts I really want to know how it is done!

**Note** that of course I can easily solve the problem outside the regex, by afterwards removing any file extension that may be there. I'm just curious now how it *can* be done *within* the regex.

I tried for hours, many failed attempts of trying to use look-ahead expressions, I think I don't quite grasp them (never used them before). I did not even begin to try to detect commented-out statements, if anyone has a solution for that special case it would just be a bonus, but

I'm trying to match path + filename in files that I don't have control over. They may even be minified, so I don't have an end-of-line to lean on, or it would be easy.

See the demo code below. The example test file deliberately looks a bit messy, I tried to put in all the weird combinations I could think of that I might encounter and that my regex would have to deal with.

Some optional background before the runnable example further down:

One thing is special for my particular case but that part is solved, see below: I don't try to match any path but only three cases: `./`, `../lib/` and "" (nothing). That's because this is about dynamic module loading, and modules are either node.js (no prefix, only some allowed), part of the core libs (`../lib/`) or destined to be loaded dynamically from somewhere during runtime (`./` - that path indicates that code of such a module tries to load another such module). I kept the filesystem paths in there so that during development code checkers like Flow and the IDE itself have a chance to find the modules, but during runtime at least that 3rd kind of modules won't be on the filesystem.

That is why during import into storage I try to parse them for their require statements: To maintain their CommonJS (node.js) synchronous nature, before actually loading a requested dynamic module I load all the dependencies (recursively). For that I need to collect what each module "require()-s" by parsing it when I put it into storage. I'm just saying that as optional piece of information, for context, I have no control over that, so I have no question about how (in)advisable that is (all of the context for *why* that is done still is missing from my description). That system *will* change, just not now.

Here is the runnable test case, ideally I would have the names without the optional extension, and the two commented-out matches removed:

```js
const testText: string = `
/**
 * There are 8 active require() statements in here and 2 commented-out ones.
 */    
const fs = require('fs'); require("../lib/store.js"); let t = require("crypto");
//OtherStuff: type defs comments etc.
let iah = require("./imap-account-handler.js"); //let iah = require("./inactive");
//let iah = require("./imap.js");
    require("./imap-mailbox-handler");
const mX = require("./modX.js"); require("./modX.js"); require("./modY.js");
otherStuff();
otherStuff();
`;

const regex: RegExp = new RegExp(
    // 1) Start indicator (account for allowed whitespace characters)
    'require\\s*\\(\\s*["\']' +
    // 2) match[1]: optional group for the prefix, which can only(!) be
    //    either "../lib" or "./"
    '(' +
        // 2.1) ...either a prefix indicating a core "One" module
        //      (captured by parent group)
        '(?:\\.\\./lib/)' +
        '|' +
        // 2.2) ...or a prefix indicating a dynamic module
        //      (captured by parent group)
        '(?:\\./)' +
    ')?' +
    // 3) match[2]: Actual module name with or without file ending. We
    //    exclude the character that stands for the directory hierarchy
    //    and the two possible quote characters, everything else is
    //    allowed: This is not a check for name validity!
    '([^/\\"\']+)' +
    // 4) End indicator
    '["\']\\s*\\)',
    // 5) Flag "g" (global)  There can be many "require(...)" commands.
    'g'
);

let m: {[index: number]: string, index: number, input: string};
let count: number = 1;

while (m = regex.exec(testText)) {
    console.log(
      `${count++}: Prefix ${m[1] || '(none)'} ${'\t'} Name ${m[2] || '(none)'}`
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip out the statements that are commented out first using a separate replace command (see line `let cleanComments`). Then, the regex:

require
( open parenthesis
['"] quote of either type
(./|../lib/)? optional prefix capture
([^'"]+?) capture group for anything that's not a quote
(?:.js) optional non-capturing group for the file extension
['"] closing quote of either type

```js
const testText: string = `
/**
 * There are 8 active require() statements in here and 2 commented-out ones.
 */    
const fs = require('fs'); require("../lib/store.js"); let t = require("crypto");
//OtherStuff: type defs comments etc.
let iah = require("./imap-account-h.andler.js"); //let iah = require("./inactive");
//let iah = require("./imap.js");
    require("./imap-mailbox-handler");
const mX = require("./modX.js"); require("./modX.js"); require("./modY.js");
otherStuff();
otherStuff();
`;
const regex = /require\(['"](\.\/|\.\.\/lib\/)?([^'"]+?)(?:\.js)?['"]/g

let m: {[index: number]: string, index: number, input: string};
let count: number = 1;

let cleanComments = testText.replace(/\/\/.+/g,"")
while (m = regex.exec(cleanComments)) {
    console.log(
      `${count++}: Prefix ${m[1] || '(none)'} ${'\t'} Name ${m[2] || '(none)'}`
    );
}
```

Comment: Good answer, not only because solving the comments issue but also simplifying the regex expression (with `regex = /.../` rather than `new RegExp('...')`), so increasing readability. I'd just suggest two slight improvements: 1) cleanComments regex might cover the case of "empty comment": `/\/\/.*/` rather than `/\/\/.+/`; 2) path capture part `([^'"]+?)` might be changed to `([^'".]+)`: also excluding dot, it avoids the `+?` (not-greedy) quantifier, so consuming less steps of the regex engine.

Comment: I initially had `([^'".]+)`, but the issue there is it wouldn't work for any filenames that include a `.` (I changed one of the filenames to `imap-account-h.andler.js` to test that exact scenario). Also for the comment, that's a good catch in general, but in this case we don't really need to care about empty comments since the only reason to check is to get rid of commented-out require statements

Comment: Yeah that's great guys, marked as answer. I deliberately wrote it as a string though, because that's the only way to spread it over multiple lines so that I can have each component individually. Here in the IDE the double backslash escapes don't look nearly as bad as having one looooooong regex on a single line. I want to optimize the speed of me editing that expression half a year from now, not the speed of the code, given that this is part of something that runs only very rarely and if then only once.

Comment: @jmcgriz You're right: I realize that looking for empty comments is overkill in this case! But I'm surprised by your position about excluding dot. Before posting my comment I'd considered the possibility that a dot exists in a file name, but concluded it _should not_: in my mind, since the extension is not mandatory, I thought that `required('some.thing')` would be seen as already having an extension, leading to a confusing situation where nobody can decide if it's really "some.thing" or "some.thing.js", so dotted file-names would be forbidden. But I must confess I didn't inquire further...

Comment: @cFreed Since this is specific to node.js - that system only cares about .js extensions. I just created a file `aaa.bbb.js` and loaded it through `require('./aaa.bbb');`. I renamed to just `aaa.bbb`, still worked. The module loader code is in here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L479

Comment: @Mörre I was just going to try that to see if it works, I thought I'd seen something like that before but wasn't sure how require behaves with dots in filenames

Comment: @Mörre Good to know! Thanks for the precision.